# Get Latest record of table via Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using code first feature of EntityFramework and I have created a model class with this field that have their own property (I don't mention them here!) :

```
public class Portrait
{
        private Guid _id;
        private string _aboutimage;
        private string _aboutMe;
        private string _mainMenu;
        private string _headerImage;
        private string _resume;
        private string _showpiece;
        private string _siteMenu;
        private string _adminMenu;
}
```

and for each part of this class I have separate ViewModel, for example I have `AboutViewModel` to update `About` in admin part and navigate in about page in website :

```
public class AboutViewModel
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string AboutText { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I update the `AboutViewModel`, `Portrait` table in database will create a record that will have about text (other field will be null)

And for updating for other part of this table like `Resume` or others, it will generate another record with updated and inserted field (now in this record about text will be null!)

Now how can I get the about field to show it in UI as I have several records !? I don't want and also can not get these field by ID because I always want to have their latest updated to show in web site, what I have written is like this ,my about action to get the about text is like this :

```
public ViewResult About()
{
            var about= _portraitRepository.GetContent();

            return View(about);
}
```

and the `GetContent()` is like this :

```
public Portrait GetContent()
{
            return _siteContext.Portraits.Find();
}
```

but dosn't work and I got this error:

> *The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity. Parameter name: keyValues*

Am I in a wrong direction? How can I solve this problem please?

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to get the Max value of the **Id** of Portrait table **if it is an identity column**.

The action will look like below.

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    var about= _portraitRepository.GetLatest();
}
```

Repository will look like below.

```
public Portrait GetLatest()
{
    var latestId = _siteContext.Portraits.Max(p => p.Id);
    return _siteContext.Portraits.Find(latestId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should retrieve the ID when you perform the insert. Then save that value to Session or something for later use in your About Action

The call to the repository to persom the insert will look like below.

```
Session["LatestPortraitId"] = _portraitRepository.AddPortrait();
```

The method in the Portrait repository used to insert a new Portrait should look like below.

```
public int AddPortrait(portrait)
{
    _siteContext.AddObject(portrait);
    _siteContext.SaveChanges();
    return portrait.Id;
}
```

The About action will look like below.

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    var latestPortraitId = Int.Parse(Session["LatestPortraitId"]); 
    var about= _portraitRepository.GetContent(latestPortraitId);
}
```

Inside the repository it should be as shown below.

```
public Portrait GetContent(int id)
{
    return _siteContext.Portraits.Find(id);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , I don't have any problem with saving the Id , but in about action (public ViewResult About()) I can't get about with Id , could I ?

Comment: Edited the answer with clarification for the question above.

Comment: but it doesn't return any result in this case !

Comment: Debug the application and check the value of Id being passed into the Find(id) method and check your database to see if it exists in Portrait table.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  when I call the about action ! it doesn't get any

Comment: Reason for the Object reference error must be attempting to access Session["LatestPortraitId"] in the About action without initializing it. Inside the About action wrap those stuff inside a null checking for Session["LatestPortraitId"]. Debugging tip: When you get an error check which line of code causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Order the search by descendent Id then use first property